# Difference between using transformer for multi-class classification and clustering using last hidden layer

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means, huggingface-transformers, feature-extraction, transformer-model

My data is a collection of URLs where I am interested in categorizing them into multiple groups.
At the moment, I am using a pre-trained transformer model and fine-tuning it according to my data with manual labeling.

My dataset can have undiscovered classes that I did not capture while labeling and also the future data also can have new categories. I want to identify the these different categories.

I am confused on what is the difference between "fine tuning a transformer model for multi-class classification and use it with a classification header for multi-class classification on new data" and "fine tuning a transformer model for multi-class classification and then extract the last hidden layer embeddings and perform clustering on them".

At the moment I am fine-tuning the model with 6 classes. Then pass through the new data on the trained model and extract the last hidden layer embeddings and cluster them.
The elbow for clustering always show 6 clusters.

Is that because there is actually only 6 categories, or am I interfering the clustering process by using a fine-tuned model for 6 classes?

Thanks
Matheesha